# Merge Rows with Date Values and remove rows with all NULL Dates

Tags: merge, sql-server-2017

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Table with a structure similar to this:

```
id | i_id | item_name    | date1      | date2      | date3     | date4     | date5     |...
---+------+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---
 1 | 1234 | item_a       | 01/01/2019 |NULL        |01/03/2019 |NULL       |...
 1 | 1234 | item_a       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |01/05/2019 |NULL       |...
 1 | 1235 | item_b       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |...
 1 | 1235 | item_b       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |...
 1 | 1235 | item_b       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |01/07/2019 |...
 2 | 1236 | item_c       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |...
 2 | 1236 | item_c       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |...
 2 | 1236 | item_c       | NULL       |NULL        |01/12/2019 |NULL       |NULL       |...
 2 | 1237 | item_d       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |01/15/2019 |...
 2 | 1237 | item_d       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |...
 3 | 1238 | item_e       | 01/18/2019 |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |...
 3 | 1238 | item_e       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |...
 3 | 1239 | item_f       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |...
 3 | 1239 | item_f       | NULL       |NULL        |NULL       |01/20/2019 |NULL       |...
```

I need to merge the rows that contain Date data by 'id' and remove those rows that do not contain any dates, similar to this:

```
id | date1      | date2     | date3     | date4     | date5     |...
---+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---
 1 | 01/01/2019 |NULL       |01/03/2019 |01/05/2019 |01/07/2019 |...
 2 | NULL       |NULL       |01/12/2019 |NULL       |01/15/2019 |...
 3 | 01/18/2019 |NULL       |NULL       |01/20/2019 |NULL       |...
```

Can anyone help me with the merging of such a data structure? There may be many 'id' records with NULL dates and a lot of additional date columns (each column in the source Table named uniquely.
Thanks,
Wayne

Ops Audrey! It looks like I was premature with my testing of your solution. When I reviewed the result set in more detail, I found that I was getting multiple rows for each 'id' value, similar to the example below:

```
id | i_id | date1      | date2      | date3      | date4      | date5      |...
---+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+---
 1 | 1234 | 01/01/2019 | NULL       | 01/03/2019 | 01/05/2019 | NULL       |...
 1 | 1235 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | 01/07/2019 |...
 2 | 1236 | NULL       | NULL       | 01/12/2019 | NULL       | NULL       |...
 2 | 1237 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | 01/15/2019 |...
 3 | 1238 | 01/18/2019 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |...
 3 | 1239 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | 01/20/2019 | NULL       |...
```

I'm still a rookie with SQL queries. Can you explain how I would merge these rows into a single row for each 'id' in the first column?
Thanks, Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter out the rows without date values, you need where clause like this:

```
where date1 is not null or date2 is not null or date3 is not null -- All date columns
```

You can shorten this a bit, if you write is using [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
where COALESCE(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5) is not null
```

Then you need to group by the rest of the rows by `ID` and aggregate the date values. I believe your data suppose to have only 1 date value by ID in one column, so you can use any aggregation function, but in case there are multiple date values, define which date you want to get. I will assume you want to get the latest date, so I will write the query using [MAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

So the final query could look like this:

```
select
    ID
    , MAX(date1) as date1
    , MAX(date2) as date2
    , MAX(date3) as date3
    , MAX(date4) as date4
    , MAX(date5) as date5
    -- Rest of the dates columns aggregated the same way
from MyTable
where COALESCE(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5 /* Rest of the date columns */) is not null
group by ID
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, Thanks for the prompt response. I had the first part for removing the NULL dates working using the first option you detailed, but I wasn't sure if I was doing that correctly. However, I didn't know about the COALESCE option, so I'll use that to reduce the length of my code. My data is supposed to have only 1 date value by ID in one column, but it is possible that this rule may be broken unless I do some error checking. I will test this out over the weekend when I will get the chance to work on it and will let you know if I got it to work. ~Wayne

Comment: Hi Audrey, Sorry for the delayed feedback, but my weekend was very busy so the extra work I intended doing was a non-starter. So back to work this week and I used the process you detailed, which worked perfectly. Thanks very much for your assistance with my query. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Per my modified question, I still need to merge each unique 'id' record into a single row in my result set.

Comment: The query from my answer will still return the result you expect.

Comment: Hmm, I checked the code and there appears to be the same logic as you have detailed above, in my listing, but I had to add the equivalent of the 'i_id' column to the Group By to get it to work. I still get each 'id' row listed separately, when more than one row of the same 'id' is found with dates. That is, it's not merging the multiple 'id' rows into a single row with that 'id'. Confusing. I guess I'll have to re-check my source data and then make sure I haven't missed anything in my logic.

Comment: If you add `i_id` to the `group by`, it will not merge the rows with same `id` values into one! `group by` means "group rows with the same values of these fields into one row". If `id` is the only column in the `group by` statement, you will get one row in the output for each id **value** (i.e. it doesn't matter is it unique or there are duplicated values). And since `i_id` is unique, if you add it to the `group by`, you will get the same number of rows as your input. So don't do that. If you explain your problem better, we may be able to give you better answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry about not being clear with my explanation. When I added the GROUP BY clause, I received an error message "Column 'i_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." So I interpreted that to mean I needed to add the 'i_id' field to the GROUP BY clause. But, do I understand correctly that I should instead either leave the 'i_id' field out of my list of columns or include it but contained within an aggregate function like the MAX function you used? I get confused with the way the GROUP BY clause works.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Only fields listed in the `group by` clause can be referenced directly in the `select` clause. All others must be in some aggregation function, like `max`, `sum`, `avg`, etc.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the confirmation and your assistance all throughout this process. With your clarifications along the way, the query is now working perfectly for me. I certainly learnt a lot through this process. I very much appreciated your help with getting me there!!!